# Wordpress: add custom ID to ul in wp_nav_menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to alter the wp_nav_menu to output the html like the below example.

```
<div class="menu">
<ul id="menu">
```

The original output

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
```

I cant do it with jQuery or javascript, Its have to be php code

Comment: Can you tell us why you need to do this?

Comment: @ChrisHerbert I Need to make the menu compatible with TinyDropdown

Answer (score 5):

[`wp_nav_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) accepts the key `menu_id` in its options array. Set it to the ID you want, e.g:

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'menu_id' => 'menu'
));
```

Comment: the output is same the original, like i'm never edit the code!!

Comment: @JimmyTodd Can you post the PHP code you're using to output the menu?

Comment: this is the code http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/9905/wpmenug.png and this is the output http://jsfiddle.net/v9rvA/

Comment: What theme are you using? Maybe it disregards the option

Comment: Are you using any other plugins that might affect the output of the menu?

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly set the id in the html by defining `items_wrap`, and make sure `walker` is not set to some custom function:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'main-menu'
    'items_wrap'     => '<ul id="menu" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'walker'         => '',
));
```

This is incomplete info; 1st attempt to use:

```
'fallback_cb'     => false,
```

If you menu doesn't appear, that means you have not created any menu and that means its taking the fallback function take care for that.

So go and create a menu first.  :D

Answer (score 1):

Giving the ul an id that's the same as the class of its container is asking for trouble, but this should work:

```
<?php

function showMenu(){
$args = array(
  'menu_id' => 'menu'
);

wp_nav_menu($args);

}

showMenu();
?>
```

The WordPress Codex has a page detailing all options for the wp_nav_menu() function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Comment: the output is same the original, like i'm never edit the code!!

Comment: Show us the output, please.

Comment: Are you sure you're editing the right file?  Are you changing the code on your local server but refreshing the remote server?  It really should add that id.

Comment: no the all work i do in localhost and i'm really sure every thing is alright, and this why it driving me crazy :(

Comment: As a test, remove wp_nav_menu() from your code completely.  If the menu is still there then something else is going on.

Comment: done it before and done it now too to be sure, when i remove the wp_nav_menu() the whole nave disappear